# Parallel programming using python's multiprocessing and process defunc

Tags: python, join, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, wait

I have a problem with creating parallel program using multiprocessing. AFAIK when I start a new process using this module (multiprocessing) I should do "os.wait()" or "childProcess.join()" to get its' exit status. But placing above functions in my program can occur in stopping main process if something happens to child process (and the child process will hang).

The problem is that if I don't do that I'll get child processes go zombie (and will be listed as something like "python < defunct>" in top listing).

Is there any way to avoid waiting for child processes to end and to avoid creating zombie processes and\or not bothering the main process so much about it's child processes?

Answer (score 2):

Though ars' answer should solve your immediate issues, you might consider looking at celery: http://ask.github.com/celery/index.html.  It's a relatively developer-friendly approach to accomplishing these goals and more.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to provide more information or actual code to figure this out.  Have you been through the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/multiprocessing.html), in particular the sections labeled "Warning"?  For example, you may be facing something like this:

> **Warning**: As mentioned above, if a child process has put items on a queue (and it has not used JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread()), then that process will not terminate until all buffered items have been flushed to the pipe.
>
> This means that if you try joining that process you may get a deadlock unless you are sure that all items which have been put on the queue have been consumed. Similarly, if the child process is non-daemonic then the parent process may hang on exit when it tries to join all its non-daemonic children.
>
> Note that a queue created using a manager does not have this issue. See Programming guidelines.